Vue 3 - How to create infinite nested (expandable rows) table?
I have a problem with nesting the expandable row components in my table.
Currently, I just created <TableSubRow /> in my <TableRow /> component, then in <TableSubRow /> I created <TableSecondSubRow />.
TableSection.vue
<template>
  <tbody>
    <TableRow
      v-for="(row, index) in p.rowsList"
      @send-time-log-element="(value) => e('sendTimeLogElement', value)"
      @send-expand-status="sendExpandStatus"
      @send-selected-row="sendSelectedRow(row)"
      :key="index"
      :headers="p.headers"
      :row="row"
      :tasksTitle="p.tasksTitle"
      :sub-tasks-title="p.subTasksTitle"
      :expandCell="p.expandCell"
      :secondExpandCell="p.secondExpandCell"
      :same-cell-titles="p.sameCellTitles"
      :theme="p.theme" />
  </tbody>
</template>

TableRow.vue
<template>
  <tr>
    <!-- row template (doesn't matter in this case) -->
  </tr>

  <TableSubRow
    v-for="element in p.row[p.tasksTitle]"
    v-if="rowExpanded"
    @send-time-log-element="(value) => e('sendTimeLogElement', value)"
    @change-check-status="checkRow(element)"
    :key="element"
    :element="element"
    :headers="p.headers"
    :row="p.row"
    :tasksTitle="p.tasksTitle"
    :sub-tasks-title="p.subTasksTitle"
    :expand-cell="p.expandCell"
    :second-expand-cell="p.secondExpandCell"
    :same-cell-titles="p.sameCellTitles"
    :theme="p.theme" />
</template>

TableSubRow.vue
<template>
  <tr>
    <!-- sub row template -->
  </tr>

  <TableSecondSubRow
    v-if="isExpanded"
    @send-time-log-element="(value) => e('sendTimeLogElement', value)"
    @change-check-status="checkRow(p.element)"
    :headers="p.headers"
    :row="p.element"
    :tasksTitle="p.tasksTitle"
    :expand-cell="p.expandCell"
    :second-expand-cell="p.secondExpandCell"
    :same-cell-titles="p.sameCellTitles" />
</template>


In this case, I had to send props for each subrow (e.g. for expand status), which is bad I think.
Of course, it works for statically defined amount of subrows.

How could I make dynamic expandable rows like on the screen above?
I tried to create a dynamic subrow component with subrow component (like recurrence?), but I had many issues there and didn't have enough time for this.
Now I need a dynamic expandable table and cannot define subrows static in code.
It should be created automatically by backend data (nested objects or something like that).

what does didn't have enough time for this mean? are you perhaps looking for a "treeview"?

@JaromandaX I was experiencing this problem few months ago, there was no time for it then (2 sub rows were enough) - doesn't matter.
Yes, I'm looking for treeview table, but cannot create that in code - as i posted.

perhaps be inspired by others who have created vue3 treeview - there are many - I remember using one for vue2 years ago, so not relevant to you
